# Can you derive the standard error of odds ratio, from a method (Kraemer and Kupfer) that derives Risk Difference (and its SE) from continuous data?

Tags: continuous-data, odds-ratio, clinical-trials

Let's say that we have a RCT trial going on and the outcome is a continuous variable. In this paper  https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/23045205/ there are 4 methods that calculate approximated odds ratios and their SE's and one that calcuates the approximated Risk Difference and its standard error. We will focus on the last method itself. If I set a control group risk of a certain number, I can then  derive the group risk of the experimental group (from the calculated RD) and therefore I can calculate the Odds Ratio. The question is, what its standard error would be. Below is the formula of the method:[image]